# powershell Search Text and if found, update next column in csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I have a field in a csv file that looks like this.
     **CN=TSCHA-MGMT01-V,OU=Virtual Workstations,OU=Acroplis,OU=Chennai,OU=WestTLRCorp,DC=jfr,DC=domain,DC=com**

I want to do a search on that field and if the word Acroplis shows up, the next field in the csv file is called Region.  I would like to fill that field with the text EMEA, and then export the file with the new data to a new csv file. 
The CSV file has the format of

domain          : apac

cn              : BJZV0053

dn              : CN=BJZV0053,OU=Thin Clients,OU=BJZ,OU=GD2_9_4,OU=Computers,OU=CN,DC=apac,DC=ime,DC=domain,DC=com

operatingSystem : Windows XP Professional

Region          :

```
$vmimport = Import-Csv "c:\Scripts\06182014VirtualData.csv"

if ($vmimport.dn | Select-String -pattern "Acroplis")
    {
    $vmimport.Region = "EMEA"}

Export-Csv C:\Scripts\RegionFinal.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're after:

```
Import-Csv "c:\Scripts\06182014VirtualData.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.dn -like "*Acroplis*") {
        $_.Region = "EMEA"
        }
    $_ | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\RegionFinal.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
```

If you need something different you'll need to clean up your sample data. For example, your sample code is looking at the `CN` field, but the example data looks like it should be using the `DN` field.

Comment: Tim, I made the change in the code.  You are correct in that I wanted DN .. not CN.  I ran the script like you have but nothing populated in the Region field :(

Comment: I got it Tim.  Acroplis was spelled wrong.  It works now!  Thanks man.